# Maximal immerged disk on a hermitian Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $S$ be a Riemann surface equipped with a hyperbolic metric, and $z_0 \in S$. 
Is there a way to estimate the maximal radius $r>0$ such that there is a holomorphic embedding $\psi : \Delta_r \rightarrow S$ such that $\psi(0)=z_0$ and $D\psi(0)$ has unit norm ? Here $\Delta_r$ is the disk of radius $r$.

I am thinking this should be connected to questions regarding the geodesics of $S$.